# How to start a chrome process and then kill it using batch file in win10

Tags: batch-file

I want to do the following :

Start chrome , then wait  and then start another chrome instance in the background. Then i would like that new instance to close after 5 seconds.

When i echo the pid it returns a number so it does get a pid.

I have tried to find the pid which i do find but using taskkill to end it says process id not found. I have also tried to store the first process ids and then compare with the new one and to kill the task with the different pid but didnt work.

Here is the code i've used :

```
"C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
goto :loop
:loop
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
set pid=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create 
"C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --
 remote-debugging-port=9222 http://google.com"^,"%~dp0." ^| find 
 "ProcessId"') do set pid=%%a
 echo %pid%
 timeout /t 10
 taskkill /PID %pid%

 goto :loop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "didnt work" is not a problem description. Also, code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or risk a look into Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You are always welcome to ask, but please keep the above in mind. :)

Comment: I've updated my post to include the code i've used